# How to solve QQuickPaintedItem crash and not rendering?

Tags: python, qt, qml

I try to show the stream of preprocessed Images so I create a custom `QQuickPaintedItem` to paint images
The problem is that when the image change, Nothing happens just the application crashes but the print statement of the paint method still prints, and the mouse cursor looks like `+` sign.

here is my `LiveCamera` subclass from `QQuickPaintedItem`

```
class LiveCamera(QQuickPaintedItem):

imageChanged=Signal(QImage)
def __init__(self):

    super().__init__()
    self.setRenderTarget(QQuickPaintedItem.FramebufferObject)

    self.m_image = QImage("C://Users//Hassan//Documents//python-gui-projects//PortMafiaSecurity//images//loading.jpg")


def paint(self,painter: QPainter):
    print('hey')
    if self.m_image.isNull(): return
    img = self.m_image.scaled(self.size().toSize(),Qt.KeepAspectRatioByExpanding ,Qt.SmoothTransformation)
    painter.drawPixmap(QPoint(),QPixmap.fromImage(img))

@Property(QImage, notify=imageChanged)
def image(self):
     return self.m_image

@image.setter
def image(self, image):
    if self.m_image == image: return
    self.m_image = image
    self.imageChanged.emit(self.m_image)
    #self.paint(QPainter())
    self.update()
```

Here is main.py

```
 class CamThread(QThread):
    def __init__(self,UI):
        super().__init__()
        self.UI=UI


    def run(self):


          cap = open_images_capture(args.input, args.loop)
          frame_processor = FrameProcessor(args)

       

          frame_num = 0
          output_transform = None

          while True:
              start_time = perf_counter()
              frame = cap.read()

              if frame_num == 0:
                  output_transform = OutputTransform(frame.shape[:2], args.output_resolution)


              detections = frame_processor.process(frame)
              frame = draw_detections(frame, frame_processor, detections, output_transform)

              frame_num += 1
              h, w, ch = frame.shape


              p = QImage(frame.data, h, w,QImage.Format_RGB888)
              self.UI.changeImage.emit(p)




class MainThread(QObject):
    def __init__(self):
         QObject.__init__(self)
         self.cam=CamThread(self)


    changeImage=Signal(QImage)

    @Slot(bool)
    def click(self,first):
        if first:
         self.cam.run()
        else:
         self.cam.quit()



if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = QGuiApplication(sys.argv)
    engine = QQmlApplicationEngine()
    main = MainThread()

    engine.rootContext().setContextProperty("cam_recording", main)
    qmlRegisterType(LiveCamera, "LiveCameraPlugin", 1, 0, "LiveCamera")

    engine.load(os.fspath(Path(__file__).resolve().parent / "qml/main.qml"))
    if not engine.rootObjects():
        sys.exit(-1)
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Here is Qml

```
Rectangle{
    x: 72
    y: 84
    width: 649
    height: 366

    LiveCamera{
        id:camera
        anchors.fill: parent
    }

}

LeftMenuBtn {
    //some stuff
}

Connections{
    target: cam_recording
    function onChangeImage(img){
            camera.image=img
    }
}
```

Is there a way to solve that problem, I tried a lot to search for a solution but I didn't find it also I tried `QtQuickImageProvider` same problem so is there a better way?

Here is [Application Crash Moment: Python is not responding](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KNsnQ.png)

Comment: Where does it crash - on which line, and what is the stack trace.

Comment: I mean GUI interface not responding and exit immediately ,the print in paint method of livecamera subclass work till i close the program.  without any warning or issues. check added output picture in post

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to the screenshot, this isn't a crash. The program seems to be too busy (on the main/gui thread) to respond to user interaction, resulting in Windows saying the application is not responsive.

To debug such a problem, you should use a debugger, pause the program and see what he is doing (on the main thread).

The problem, in this case, is that you are running `CamThread::run` (which executes an infinite loop) inside the main thread, instead of running it on a separate thread as intended. You shouldn't call `QThread::run` explicitly, but call [`QThread::start`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qthread.html#start), which will start a new thread and execute the `QThread::run` function on that new thread.

Note that [`QThread::quit`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qthread.html#quit) does nothing in your case, as by reimplementing [`QThread::run`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qthread.html#run), the `QEventLoop` isn't started on that thread. Either you should start the event loop or you should implement your own signal, to interrupt the infinite loop inside `CamThread::run` to let the thread finish gracefully.

Comment: Thanks a lot bro, it work like magic . you  gave me a great lesson to not assume things work as I think